# Blazor WASM - Exception rendering component. The error was: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have two razor pages with WASM and .NET Core Minimal APIs, and I'm getting an unexpected error while trying to navigate between them passing a parameter I get from an API call in the first one. They are as follows:

First One

```
@page "/"
@using Client.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager


<PageTitle>Simple Application</PageTitle>

<h1>Simple Application</h1>



<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered border-dark table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ContactId (PK)</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @if (_contacts != null)
            {
                @foreach (var contact in _contacts)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">@contact.ContactId</th>
                        <td>@contact.FirstName</td>
                        <td>@contact.LastName</td>
                        <td>@contact.Email</td>
                        <td>@contact.PhoneNumber</td>
                        <td>
                            <button @onclick="() => NavigateToEdit(contact.ContactId)" class=" btn btn-success w-100">
                                History
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


@code {

#pragma warning disable CS8618
    [Inject]
    protected HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }
#pragma warning disable CS8618

    private List<Contact>? _contacts = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _contacts = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Contact>?>(Endpoints.ContactsAll);
    }

    private void NavigateToEdit(int ContactId)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"EditList/{ContactId}");
    }
}
```

Second One:

```
@page "/EditList/{contactId}"
@using Client.Components
@using Common.Models

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Edits of the Contact</PageTitle>


<h1>Edits of the Contact</h1>

<button @onclick="() => NavigateToIndex()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg w-100 mb-3">
    Back to Index
</button>


<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered border-dark table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">EditId (PK)</th>
                <th scope="col">ContactId</th>
                <th scope="col">UpdateTime</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @if (_edits != null)
            {
                @foreach (var edit in _edits)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <th scope="row">@edit.EditId</th>
                        <td>@edit.ContactId</td>
                        <td>@edit.UpdateTime</td>
                        <td>@edit.FirstName</td>
                        <td>@edit.LastName</td>
                        <td>@edit.Email</td>
                        <td>@edit.PhoneNumber</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


@code {

    #pragma warning disable CS8618
    [Inject]
    protected HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }
    #pragma warning disable CS8618

    [Parameter]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    private List<Edit>? _edits = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _edits = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Edit>?>(Endpoints.EditsById(ContactId));
    }

    private void NavigateToIndex()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"Index");
    }
}
```

When trying to click the button in the second screen, I get the following (please note that ContactId is an int):

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to set property 'ContactId' on object of type 'Client.Pages.EditList'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Full output:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to set property 'ContactId' on object of type 'Client.Pages.EditList'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to set property 'ContactId' on object of type 'Client.Pages.EditList'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
 ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.PropertySetter.CallPropertySetter[EditList,Int32](Action`2 setter, Object target, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.PropertySetter.SetValue(Object target, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.<SetProperties>g__SetProperty|3_0(Object target, PropertySetter writer, String parameterName, Object value)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.<SetProperties>g__SetProperty|3_0(Object target, PropertySetter writer, String parameterName, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.SetProperties(ParameterView& parameters, Object target)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView.SetParameterProperties(Object target)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters)
The program '[22776] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
The thread 0x0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program 'localhost:7206' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
The program '' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
The program '' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Tried using UriHelper, converting contactId to String. Nothing worked.

Comment: What is your `'Client.Pages.EditList'`?

Comment: It is the name of the second page. It is located in the Pages folder inside the Client project. EditList.razor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `contactId` as `int` for the route (`@page`).

> EditList.razor

```
@page "/EditList/{contactId:int}"
```

---

**References**

[ASP.NET Core Blazor routing and navigation (Route Constraints section)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-constraints)

Comment: I found the solution and came back to see you've posted it also! Thank you very much!